# ffmpeg copying rtmp stream, but without audio

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, flash-media-server, flashmedialiveencoder

I am sending stream to flash media server from Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder and I am trying to copy this stream to another FMS using FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -i "rtmp://x.x.x.x/live/stream1 live=1" \
  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://y.y.y.y/live/stream1
```

but there is no audio. Can anyone help me?

Comment: this is output for copied string

'frame=  488 fps= 25 q=31.0 Lsize=    1148kB time=00:00:19.60 bitrate= 479.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=96
video:1140kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.714349%'

Answer (score 0):

try like this :
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://x.x.x.x/live/stream1 live=1" \
  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://y.y.y.y/live/stream1

Comment: It would really help if you actually explained the solution rather than just posting some random code